# How to handle idle in android application using android annotation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have already code like this, but the problem is when the user has interaction with another app while the app is minimized.. I dont know how to check the idle time while using the other app.. I am also using android-annotation for my app.

```
public void onUserInteraction() {
    resetDisconnectTimer();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();//how to check the idle time 

    resetDisconnectTimer();//handler
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you need to calculate the time of an application which is minimized or not in foreground till it opens again! Is it right?

Comment: yeah.. but how? this is what im using while app idle but i dont know when in other app disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, (DataConstants.SESSION_TIMEOUT * 60 * 1000));//handler

Comment: You want to calculate for other apps or only your app?

Comment: for only in my app.. because my handler didn't work the idle handler while you using other app

Comment: Don't make it complex! Just go through the possible issues. The problem here is u can start the time and stop the timer in onPause() and onResume() methods. But these methods will be called onClick of Home button and also when you navigate to next activity. So this can be little complex. But you can get the foreground running applications using ActivityManager. Try whether this will help you or not!

Comment: @Shin: Why do you need to know how long your app has been idle? Your `disconnectCallback` will be called after `SESSION_TIMEOUT` (unless the message is reset) even if your app is not in the foreground. Isn't that what you want?